# How to create a Akka streams true pull stream with async stages

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I'm trying to create a Source that provides OAuth2 tokens and that also takes care of refreshing expired tokens.
Currently my code looks a bit like this

```scala
  case class Token(expires: Instant = Instant.now().plus(100, ChronoUnit.MILLIS)){
    def expired = Instant.now().isAfter(expires)
  }

  Source
    .repeat()
    .mapAsync(1){ _ =>
      println("  -> token req")
      // this fakes an async token request to the token service
      Future{
        Thread.sleep(500)
        println("  <- token resp")
        Token()
      }
    }
    .mapAsync(1){ token =>
      println("  -> req with token auth")
      if(token.expired){
        println("!!! Received expired token")
      }
      // this is the actual call that needs the token
      println("making call")
      Future{
        Thread.sleep(2000)
        println("  <- req resp")
        "OK"
      }
    }
    .take(2)
    .runWith(Sink.ignore)
    .recover{case e => ()}
    .flatMap{ _ =>
      system.terminate()
    }
```

Output of this code looks like this

```
root   -> token req
root   <- token resp
root   -> token req
root   -> req with token auth
root making call
root   <- token resp
root   -> token req
root   <- token resp
root   -> token req
root   <- token resp
root   -> token req
root   <- req resp
root   -> req with token auth
root !!! Received expired token
root making call
root   <- token resp
root   -> token req
root   <- token resp
root   -> token req
root   <- token resp
root   <- req resp
root   -> req with token auth
root !!! Received expired token
root making call
root ... finished with exit code 0
```

Clearly this mapAsync(1) is producing demand when not expected (prefetching?)

There are 2 issues:

- demand causes unneeded token requests upstream
- the pre-fetching/caching of the tokens is problematic as they are only valid for a specific amount of time

So how do I create a true pull stream that behaves like this function?

`def tokenSource: () => Future[Token]`

Answer (score 3):

If you are purposefully trying to avoid pre-fetching and queuing then I think [`scala.collection.immutable.Stream`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Stream), or Iterator, is a better solution than akka Stream.

Below is an example implementation that avoids the pitfalls you enumerated in your question.  (Note: I used an [`ActorSystem`](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.4.0/?_ga=1.71912475.988023905.1442763616#akka.actor.ActorSystem) to create the ExecutionContext, via `dispatcher`, to prevent the application from exiting before the `sleep` invocations have time to complete.  I'm taking advantage of the fact that an ActorSystem does not shut down just because the main function reaches the end of the expression definition.)

```
import scala.collection.immutable.Stream
import scala.concurrent.Future

object ScalaStreamTest extends App {    
  case class Token(expires: Long = System.currentTimeMillis() + 100){
    def expired = System.currentTimeMillis() > expires
  }

  val actorSystem = akka.actor.ActorSystem()      
  import actorSystem.dispatcher

  def createToken =  Future {
    Thread.sleep(500)
    println("  <- token resp")
    Token()
  }

  def checkExpiration(token : Future[Token]) = token map { t =>
    println("  -> req with token auth")
    if(t.expired){println("!!! Received expired token")}
    t
  }

  def makeCall(token : Future[Token]) = token flatMap { t =>
    println("making call")
    Future {
      Thread.sleep(2000)
      println("  <- req resp")
      "OK"
    }
  }

  val stream = Stream.continually(createToken)
                     .map(checkExpiration)
                     .map(makeCall)
                     .take(2)
                     .force
}//end object ScalaStreamTest
```

A `force` call is necessary because a Stream is lazy and therefore all method calls before the force (namely: continually, map, & take) are also lazy.  No computation would occur on the lazy Stream unless a reducer is called or the Stream is explicitly told to via force.

Answer (score 0):

Akka Streams always prefetch to keep the pipeline saturated.

To get what you want I suggest that you create a Source[Token] that emits new Tokens when the old one expires rather than on request. Then you *zip* your Source of data with the source of Tokens and use the result of that.

Comment: But the in-flight (prefetched) tokens can still expire before they get used?

Comment: Tokens can always expire—there is no *guarantee* that your CPU will schedule a specific Thread at a specific point in time.

Comment: for a slow stream (2 msg / day) this can be a problem for fast streams there is indeed no problem

Comment: I don't see what the problem would be. the Source[Token] would emit valid tokens so the only problem would be if the processing takes longer than they are valid.

Comment: There is always minimally 1 token prefetched from Source[Token] which at the time it gets used (12h later) might be invalid.

Comment: The downstream needs to deal with expiry anyway?